# Ionic on Android 4.0.4

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

Learning hybrid app development. Made simple app and everything looked great on my HTC m8 device. But when tried the same code on Sony Xperia 4.0.4 - everything suddenly looks terrible:
- buttons are outside the screen
- scrolling behaves very strange, some elements are arbitrarily shifted
- "click" action doesn't work (had to do a workaround)
- application feels very sluggish, and almost unusalbe

This is my first experiment with hybrid apps. Is that something people often encounter? Or should I check twice all my custom CSS, and try to tweak around? Alternatively I'm considering using embedded browser with "Crosswalk".

Current stack:
- Meteor.js
- Meteoric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the issues on the Meteoric project, a few other people have had css issues on certain devices. Meteoric is in beta and is actively being updated and maintained. It might be worth adding an issue to their tracker so that they can improve their project.

https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic

Comment: Thanks for response, I'll post anything that I can confirm is related to Ionic. In this particular case I was able to get rid of some issues by "lightning up" my custom CSS (not Ionic), and reworking HTML. So Ionic actually was not responsible.